# "Charts"(IOS) xcode 9.0 compile ERROR: "static var 'defaultFormatter' is not public"

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-charts

```
"Charts"(IOS-danielgindi)
```

Everything was fine on Xcode 8.
However, Errors show up after compiled to `pod version '3.0.3'`
After the release of `pod version '3.0.4'`, I updated the pod and still show the following errors.

They are the same type of errors -

```
static var 'defaultFormatter' is not public
```

And showing

```
Static var 'defaultFormatter' is internal and cannot be referenced from a default argument value
```

inside the Charts files.
Sometime show 6 errors and sometime show 8 errors.

I am kind of newbie in swift and not sure how to solve this problems.
Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Errors shows folling .swift file:

```
ChartAxisLabelGeneratorDate
ChartAxisLabelsGeneratorNumber
ChartAxisLabelsGeneratorNumberSuffix
ChartAxisValueDouble
ChartAxisValueDoubleScreenLoc
ChartAxisValueFloat
ChartAxisValueFloatScreenLoc
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just got this to compile, at least.  If you look here: https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/commit/46a8fd70c10b38c2a3fa5862418f106ee218c388

it looks like there is a commit that addresses this.  I'm not sure why that didn't come down via Cocoapods but I'm a newb at that so I probably just did something wrong.  What I ended up doing was just putting 'public' in front of each of the default formatter declarations.  So this:

```
static var defaultFormatter: DateFormatter = {
```

changed to:

```
public static var defaultFormatter: DateFormatter = {
```

See if that takes care of it for you.

Comment: Do not include comments in the answer section. since you do not have enough rep for comments, you should have favorited the post and looked back at it later

Answer (score 0):

I find out the problem now.
I have 2 chart library, i-schuetz/SwiftCharts & danielgindi/Charts.
But I'm using only danielgindi/Charts now.
I thought it is the compile problems of danielgindi/Charts, but actually it is the compile problems of i-schuetz/SwiftCharts.

Sorry for my low level mistake.
Thanks for everyone helps!